# Is it possible to underclock ram

Tags: memory, undervolting

There is an application called granola for windows that can be used to underclock the cpu to consume less power. 
Is there also an application that can be used to underclock the ram to consume less power when you are just using the computer to download?

Comment: For Windows?  I know you can use parameters at boot to tell GRUB to use less RAM in Linux...  Perhaps there's a way to do it with Windows too.

Comment: Sorry, but using less RAM does not equate to powering less RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an OEM motherboard, you can underclock RAM by putting slower RAM in, in place of your standard RAM. Your motherboard will read the SPD and use the timings there.

If you have an aftermarket motherboard (such as Asus or Gigabyte), it may come with an overclocker's utility (Windows application) that allows you to change settings such as the FSB multiplier (or HT or QPI). This would allow you to run the RAM slower. There will be a small but measurable performance hit. Usually these utilities overvolt automatically for overclocking, I don't think they undervolt automatically though.

For true flexibility in undervolting/underclocking, any motherboard oriented towards overclockers should give you the functionality you need to do what you want, but you will probably find it in the BIOS setup, not in an application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can underclock RAM.  The best way to do so is to use any utility that will allow you to read the SPD entries.  Look for the lowest frequency spec common to all DIMMs.  Then enter those settings manually into your BIOS.  If you're BIOS doesn't have advanced config options you can use SetFSB, FreeSFB, or a proprietary utility provided by your motherboard manufacturer.  There are probably other software packages as well.

Suggestions:

1. you should read up about what all the timings do.  Generally timings are measured in clock cycles so **increasing** their value reduces energy use/performance.  There are optimum clocks, however, and going too slow will cause corruption of data so once again start with the slowest figures common to the SPD of all DIMMs.
2. You can also undervolt your RAM if you're wanting to reduce energy use.  It's entirely viable, but will take some trial and error.  Not to sound like a broken record, but start with the lowest figures common to the SPD of all DIMMs.
3. RAM doesn't use much energy so if energy reduction is your objective look to other parts of your system first.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no you can't underclock the RAM in realtime, RAM is constantly used and the moment you boot up it stores all information for you to use your system, if anything like the speed is changed then it'll crash the system.

Do underclock you have to tdo this through the BIOS.