# How do you underclock RAM (with Gigabyte F2 UEFI)?

Tags: memory, cpu, bios, uefi, underclock

I've purchased an AMD A10 7850K with a Gigabyte GA-F2A88XM-D3HP and 8GB 2400MHz Corsair RAM for my computer. The problem is that the AMD A10 7850K doesn't support RAM at 2400 MHz, so I'm trying to underclock it to 2133 MHz, which is supported. At 2400 MHz, the computer frequently gives BSOD errors, so underclocking is a must. The UEFI, however, only allows me to set the frequency to 1333 MHz, which is way too slow for my computer to function properly, or 2400 MHz by selecting the XMP (eXtreme Memory Profile), which is too fast. Does anyone know how to underclock RAM, preferable with the Gigabyte F2 UEFI?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what settings you do have?

Comment: How exaclty memory be "too slow' or "too fast" for a system?

Comment: Changing the XMP mode and/or the (timing and voltage) will "underclock" memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to underclock ram](http://superuser.com/questions/159760/is-it-possible-to-underclock-ram)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as I'm asking for instruction rather than possibility. With too slow, I mean the computer's performance is significantly slow. With too fast, I mean that the incompatible high speed causes BSOD errors. I'm trying to set the clock to a frequency that isn't available through the default profiles.

Comment: Go down to "Memory Timing Mode" and change that from "Auto", that will hopefully allow you to adjust the settings you need.

Comment: @JaïrPaalman if you could let us know if Mokubai's suggestion works... I'd be interested to find out.

Comment: @Mokubai Could you post your last reply as an answer instead? If your suggestion works, I can pass it on.

Comment: If changing the timing mode doesn't work just change the System Memory Multipler to something else other then 13.33 which is how your getting 1333MHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the answer myself, but thanks anyways for trying to help. In the help menu of the Gigabyte F2 BIOS, there was a message that said that the + and - buttons could also be used to navigate between option. I tried doing this with the system memory multiplier, and I finally got the result I wanted. I could select any common clock setting to 2400MHz. Setting the clock to 2133 MHz fixed the BSODs.